# I changed the A Name for blog.subdomain.com to a static IP address, but why is it only working for the home page?

Tags: wordpress

I'm hosting my WordPress blog with a separate host server (Dreamhost) with a static IP address. I changed the A record for blog.domain.com to the static IP address.

Now, blog.domain.com is mapped to my WordPress install, but only the homepage. If I go to any other page, it's IP Address/article-title.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean your homepage links you to http://your.ip-adress/whatever? If so, the problem is in your wordpress config. Teach it about your blog.domain.com.

Comment: blog.subdomain.com goes to blog.subdomain.com. All the links on blog.subdomain.com are pointed to http://ip-address/whatever.

Comment: So, teach your wordpress install not to do that. This is not a DNS problem, but a problem in your wordpress config.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I do have the WordPress Address URL set as http://blog.domain.com, but I didn't change the Site Address URL. Should I change that, or should I just rewrite the URLs in .htaccess?

Comment: You need to change the site url. This is all done when *generating the pages*, so nothing besides wordpress has anythong to do with it, not htaccess, not dns. Only wordpress.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer what was a stupid question in hindsight.

Answer (score 0):

An A record only points a root domain or sub domain (ex. mydomain.com or blog.mydomain.com) to an IP address. Any redirection that has to do with folders, protcols or ports, is dealt with by either the webserver (apache or similar) or by the webpage code itself.

As Dennis commented on, this seems to have some issues regarding the configuration/installation on the wordpress side. I would start by looking at the site's url configuration and functions url configuration, as per the following post:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: Thanks for the answer and providing a link. I'd give you an upvote if I could.